# What type of books to read to improve Academic English?

Tags: reading, language

Are novels good type for that purpose?

Comment: "Novels" covers a very wide range of literature, from the "scrofulous French novel" Browning describes to the world's greatest literature.  Perhaps you could edit your question to provide more focus.  Also, it seems reading academic papers, which you should be doing anyway, might be a better way to improve one's academic English.

Answer (score 6):

The best book is one you will actually read. Your English won't improve by looking guiltily at that tome gathering dust on your nightstand because it's a slog to get through. So yes, novels (in your favorite genre) are excellent for that purpose.

Academic English isn't *that* different from regular English. Once you have a firm command of English, picking up the academic style is just a matter of reading a few papers in your area.

Answer (score 3):

Read the news from some reliable English language sources, e.g., the New York Times or the Wall Street Journal, not Breitbart.  Reliable news sources all follow current style guides, which authors of books do not.  Notice how news organizations distinguish reporting from analysis from opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I found that Academic articles are the best option to choose. They are written differently from other types and - in particular if you pick articles from your field - you will end up with a terminological collection that might be helpful for you in writing your paper. This is based on my personal experience,,

Answer (score -1):

This may be better on the English stack, but good novels yes, others probably not ie anything containing profanity as that is not used in professional reports.